# How many solutions of the equation $ax^2 +by^2 = 1$ are there with $(x, y) ∈ \mathbb{F}_{p} ×\mathbb{F}_{p}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields

How many solutions of the equation $ax^2 +by^2 = 1$ are there with $(x, y) ∈ \mathbb{F}_{p} ×\mathbb{F}_{p}$
where $a, b$ are integers whose product is not divisible by $p$?

This was a recommended problem from my professor for algebraic number Theory, any insight into the best method of solving this or similar problems would be appreciated.

edit: $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ is a prime
edit 2: I do not believe this is a duplicate. In the claimed possible duplicate, you assume the number os solutions and go about proving $gcd(ab,p) = 1$. My proof would go the other way, and still the questions differ in the fact

Comment: What does $F_p$ mean?

Comment: The field of p elements, where p is prime.

Comment: I will look at this possible duplicate and see if that gives any illumination on my question then will edit my post accordingly.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I don't know the exact protocol. I answered the question even though it was a duplicate. Let me know if that was the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I usually recommend that answers to (potential) duplicates should be posted to the original. Your answer gives a sufficiently different perspective that it would defend itself nicely nicely in the other thread as well (answering it there would "bump" that thread to the front page also)! I guess at this point it may be best to wait whether this actually is closed as a dupe or not. If it gets closed, we can ask the diamond moderators to merge the two threads, which would conveniently also relocate your answer without further ado. Let's wait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's probably, at least to me, the most illuminating solution. Let $C$ be the curve defined by $ax^2+by^2-1=0$. We're essentially trying to compute $\# C(\mathbb{F}_p)$. Well, the answer, as it turns out, is $p-\left(\dfrac{-ab}{p}\right)$.

Why? Where is this subtractive 'error term' coming from? Most of the solutions don't really explain this point, they just manipulate some sums of Legendre symbols. I once taught a number theory course where this was one of the main points of the class-- to understand more deeply where this error term comes from.

The point is that $C$ is an affine curve which has a projective closure $Z$ which is the curve cut out by $V(ax^2+by^2-z^2)\subseteq \mathbb{P}^2_{\mathbb{F}_p}$. Now, this is a smooth (because $a,b\in\mathbb{F}_p^\times$) projective curve of genus $0$. Moreover, $Z(\mathbb{F}_p)\ne\varnothing$. This is clear from a simple counting argument ($\# C(\mathbb{F}_p)\ne 0$ else the sets $\{ax^2\}$ and $\{1-by^2\}$ have no overlaps, but they both have $\frac{p-1}{2}+1$ elements which would produce $p+1$ elements of $\mathbb{F}_p$ if they were disjoint). But, then classical geometry tells you that if $x_0\in Z(\mathbb{F}_p)$ then geometrically projecting away from $x_0$ gives you a bijection (isomorphism)

$$\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{F}_p)\to Z(\mathbb{F}_p)$$

More geometrically, we can identify $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{F}_p)$ with the set $\mathscr{L}$ lines $\ell$ in $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ that pass through $x_0$. We then get a natural bijection

$$\mathscr{L}\to Z(\mathbb{F}_p)$$

by taking $\ell$ to the unique point of $Z(\mathbb{F}_p)$ other than $x_0$ in $\ell\cap Z(\mathbb{F}_p)$ (you need to prove that there is such a unique intersection point).

Of course, if you know algebraic geometry this has a much cleaner explanation. Namely, if $Z$ is a (geometrically integral smooth) genus $0$ curve over a field $k$ and $x_0\in Z(k)$ then $\deg \mathcal{O}(x_0)=1\geqslant 2(0)+1$ so that $\mathcal{O}(x_0)$ is very ample. But, on the other hand, we know from Riemann-Roch that

$$h^0(\mathcal{O}(x_0))-h^1(\mathcal{O}(x_0))=\deg(\mathcal{O}(x_0))+1-0=2$$

but by Serre duality and the fact that $\deg(\omega_Z)=2g-2=-2$ we see that

$$h^1(\mathcal{O}(x_0))=h^0(\mathcal{O}(-x_0)\otimes \omega_Z)=0$$

since $\deg(\mathcal{O}(-x_0)\otimes \omega_Z)=-3$. Thus, $h^0(\mathcal{O}(x_0))=2$. Since we know that $\mathcal{O}(x_0)$ is very ample we get a closed embedding $Z\hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$. But, since these are both smooth curves we get $Z\cong \mathbb{P}^1$.

Anyways, the point is that since $Z(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is in bijection with $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{F}_p)$ we know that $\# Z(\mathbb{F}_p)=p+1$. Note that $C\subseteq Z$ is an open subset with (reduced) complement $D=V(ax^2+by^2)$. So, we see that

$$\# C(\mathbb{F}_p)+\# D(\mathbb{F}_p)=\# Z(\mathbb{F}_p)=p+1$$

So,

$$\# C(\mathbb{F}_p)=p+1-\# D(\mathbb{F}_p)$$

But, what is $\# D(\mathbb{F}_p)$? Well, note that since we're in projective space the solutions to the equation $ax^2=-by^2$ are essentially, up to scaling, the number of solutions to $x^2=-a^{-1}b$. This is just $1+\left(\dfrac{-a^{-1}b}{p}\right)$ or, since the Legendre symbol doesn't care about inverses, $1+\left(\dfrac{-ab}{p}\right)$.

Thus, in conclusion, we see that

$$\# C(\mathbb{F}_p)=p-\frac{-ab}{p}=(p+1)-\left(1+\left(\dfrac{-ab}{p}\right)\right)$$

and we understand where this magical error term of $1+\left(\dfrac{-ab}{p}\right)$ comes from. It can't be seen from $C$ itself, but by the fact that $C$ is an open subset of a space $Z$ with good point count, and this error term is accounting for the number of points boundary of $C$ in $Z$.