# Smooth irreducible curves over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth, projective, irreducible curve in $\mathbb C\mathbb P^n$ defined over $\mathbb Q$.

1. Is it true that if its genus is $0$ then $C(\mathbb Q)$ is isomorphic with $\mathbb Q\mathbb P^1$ (over $\mathbb Q$)?
2. I understand that Mordell's theorem says that if genus is $1$ then $C(\mathbb Q)$ is either empty or finitely generated, and
3. Falting's theorem says that for $g\geq 2$, $C(\mathbb Q)$ is finite.

Is there a (fairly elementary) textbook discussing these statements?

Answer (score 2):

The curve $X^2+Y^2+Z^2=0$ in $\Bbb P^2$ is of genus zero but not isomorphic
over $\Bbb Q$ to $\Bbb P^1(\Bbb Q)$ (since it has no points over $\Bbb Q$).

Good luck finding an elementary book discussing Faltings' theorem beyond simply mentioning it. (Although Bombieri found a simpler proof than Faltings' that's far from easy).

Comment: Thanks! I understand though that if $C$ of genus $0$ has a rational point then $C(\mathbb Q)= \mathbb P^1(\mathbb Q).$ Correct? Would there be a simple reference for that?

Comment: @Adam I discuss (the well-known) proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3201863/how-many-solutions-of-the-equation-ax2-by2-1-are-there-with-x-y-%e2%88%88-ma/3202865#3202865

Comment: @Adam PS, I don't know what your level is at, but there is at least a very famous heuristic for why the Mordell conjecture should be true. See this: https://mathoverflow.net/a/56016/38867